# How to check input between min & max number in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have 2 costs min & max. I want when user type number in input manually then the user can only type number between min & max number. i want to do it in React/Next js.

```
<Input
    value={tripCoverage}
    onChange={(e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const { minCost, maxCost } =
            studentPrice()?.tripCost || {};
        const result = Math.max(
            minCost,
            Math.min(maxCost, Number(value))
        );
        setTripCoverage(result);
    }}
    type="number"
/>
```

Comment: If your min is `5` and max is `20`, what would happen if the user want to type `12` and started typing `1` first? Does it become `5` automatically?

Comment: yes. but i want user only can type between 5-20 number.

Comment: Then how could the user type `12` without typing `1` first? You shouldn't do anything in the `change` event to restrict inputs, or at least not without a delay.

Comment: means, i have min=10 & max=20. i want user can only type 10-20 like 10,11,12.....20

Comment: Yes, but `1` is still smaller than `10`. Even if your logic works, typing `1` will instantly become `10`, and the `0` cannot be deleted.

Comment: do you any idea? how can i do it?

Comment: If you have to change the input on the fly. Try adding a delay, or running the logic with `onBlur` event instead of `onChange`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `min` and `max` attributes available on `number` type inputs.

```
const { minCost, maxCost } = studentPrice()?.tripCost;

<Input
    value={tripCoverage}
    type="number"
    min={minCost}
    max={maxCost}
    // onChange handler...
/>
```

Comment: not working what i exactly want - https://wm6f82-5173.csb.app/

Comment: @MdHaiderHossain I'm not authorised to view it. Please change the visibility.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/live/846bb1b3-45dd-40ed-8f3a-666fc561d7cd

Comment: @MdHaiderHossain the example is using `min` and `max` attributes